# Spring / Eclipselink / MySQL application data issue

Tags: java, mysql, spring, transactions, eclipselink

I'm experiencing an odd issue with my application. I have implemented an coupon rating functionality. According to the application, i have to search a coupon, and click on it which will show a description page, and there is a rating option there which is used to do preferred rating for the user. What i'm testing is the following scenario: I search coupon "Test", click on it to and go to the description page, and rate it, and check whether it is reflected in DB. The latest rated value and the total rating will be reflected in the description page. Then i go back to home page again, search the same coupon, click on it to go to its description page and rate again. What happens is, the db gets updated correctly for 4-6 times, after that when i search that coupon and go to the description page, it shows a previous value for rating and total rating which might be the value when it was rated few times ago (This value has been overridden in db). And then if i rate on top of it, the values are not updated in DB. And from there onwards, this functionality breaks. I tried several option, disabled cache, set some hits to eclipselink etc, but nothing solved the issue. Please share your suggestions. Some important parts from my code:

Persistence.xml:

```
<shared-cache-mode>NONE</shared-cache-mode>
<property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false"/>
<property name="eclipselink.query-results-cache" value="false"/>
```

Coupon and CouponRating has uni-directional one-to-one mapping: (Earlier i used bidirectional mapping, then also the same problem was there.)

In CouponRating.java:

```
@Cacheable(false)
@Entity
@Table(name = "Coupon_Rating")
public class CouponsRatings {
....
....
....
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="coupon_id", unique=true, nullable=false, updatable=false)
private Coupon coupon;

@Version
@Column(name="version")
private long version;

@Column(name="uuid") 
private String uuid;
....
....
....

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 3;
    hash = 89 * hash + (this.uuid != null ? this.uuid.hashCode() : 0);
    hash = 89 * hash + Long.valueOf(this.version).intValue();
    return hash;
}

    @Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
  if((obj == null) || (this.getClass() != obj.getClass()))
        return false;

  CouponsRatings couponsRatings = (CouponsRatings)obj;
  return (this.version == couponsRatings.getVersion() &&
    this.uuid.equalsIgnoreCase(couponsRatings.getUuid()));
}
....
....
```

RatingManagerImpl.java

```
....
....

@Transactional
public CouponsRatings saveRating(CouponsRatings rating) throws AppException{
    return ratingDAO.saveRating(rating);
}

@Transactional
public CouponsRatings updateRating(CouponsRatings rating)
        throws AppException {
    return ratingDAO.updateRating(rating);
}

public CouponsRatings findRatingById(Long id) {
    return ratingDAO.findRatingById(id);
}

public CouponsRatings refreshObject(CouponsRatings rating) {
    return ratingDAO.refreshObject(rating);
}

....
....
```

In RatingDao:

```
....
....
private EntityManager entityManager;

@PersistenceContext
public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
this.entityManager = entityManager;
}

@Override
public CouponsRatings saveRating(CouponsRatings rating) throws AppException {
try {
       entityManager.persist(rating);
} catch (Exception e) {
   logger.debug("Error in saving coupon. Reason: " + e.getMessage());
   throw new CouponzleAppException(e.getMessage());
}
return rating;
}

@Override
public CouponsRatings findRatingByCouponId(Long id) {
  CouponsRatings couponsRatings = null;
  try {
    couponsRatings = (CouponsRatings) entityManager
            .createNamedQuery("findRatingByCouponId")
            .setHint(QueryHints.CACHE_USAGE, 
                             CacheUsage.DoNotCheckCache)
            .setParameter(1, id).getSingleResult();
       } catch (NoResultException exception) {
        logger.error("No active couponsRatings available for coupon id : "
                    + id);
       }
    return couponsRatings;
}

@Override
public CouponsRatings updateRating(CouponsRatings rating)
        throws AppException {
    CouponsRatings updatedRating = null;
    try {
        updatedRating = entityManager.merge(rating);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.debug("Error in updating coupon. Reason: " + .getMessage());
        throw new AppException(e.getMessage());
    }
    return updatedRating;
}

@Override
public CouponsRatings refreshObject(CouponsRatings rating) {
    CouponsRatings updatedRating = null;
    updatedRating = entityManager.merge(rating);
    entityManager.refresh(updatedRating);
    return rating;
    }
```

From Action class: (Only the retreiving and updating senario)

```
// this sometimes loads old date as i have described
couponsRating = ratingsManager.findRatingByCouponId(Long.valueOf(
                couponId).longValue());

cupnsRating.setCurrentRating(currentRating);
cupnsRating.setLastRatingDate(new Date());
cupnsRating.setRatingSum(ratingSum);
cupnsRating.setTotalRatings(totalRatings);
couponsRating = ratingsManager.updateRating(cupnsRating);
// I tried to refresh updated object after i get the issue, but still no luck:
// couponsRating = ratingsManager.refreshObject(couponsRating);
```

Please let me know if i'm doing something wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Your refreshObject is returning the unrefreshed rating that was passed into the method rather than the refreshed version.  This might be why changes are not being made even after a refresh. Also, while it looks more simple than getting the primary key and calling find, Merge within the method has the added overhead of determining changes and merging them unneccessarily.

Answer (score 0):

Check how the ratingsManager is stored and reused.  My guess is that there are multiple instances, and each is storing its own EntityManager instance.  The EntityManager has a cache, similar to a transaction, so it will not see changes made in the scope of other EntityManagers unless its copy of the entity is refreshed.

If this is the case, you can try calling refresh (after fixing your refreshObject method to return the refreshed object and then reapply the changes), or evict/clear the entity from the EntityManager at appropriate times so that entities are reloaded from the database.